# Call of class in python with attributes

Tags: python, init, class-variables

I made a typo with the `__init__()` in line 23, but my program runs only with this failure and shows the right result. Could some experienced OOP expert help me please.

If I correct this tripple underscore `___init__()` to the correct on `__init__(file_path)` I get this ERROR for Line 53:

```
con = Contact('dummy.xml')
TypeError: Contact.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Here is a `dunmy.xml` for test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<phonebooks>
  <phonebook name="Telefonbuch">
    <contact>
      <category>0</category>
      <person>
        <realName>Dummy, Name, Street</realName>
      </person>
      <telephony nid="1">
        <number type="work" prio="1" id="0">012345678</number>
      </telephony>
      <services />
      <setup />
      <features doorphone="0" />       
      <!-- <mod_time>1587477163</mod_time> -->          
      <uniqueid>358</uniqueid>
    </contact>
    <contact>
      <category>0</category>
      <person>   
        <realName>Foto Name</realName>
      </person>       
      <telephony nid="1">
        <number type="home" prio="1" id="0">067856743</number>           
      </telephony>
      <services />       
      <setup /> 
      <features doorphone="0" />   
      <mod_time>1547749691</mod_time>  
      <uniqueid>68</uniqueid>  
    </contact>
  </phonebook> 
</phonebooks>
```

And here my program which work with the TYPO:

```
import psutil
import timeit

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class Phonebook:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        """Split tree in contact branches """
        self.file_path = file_path
    
    def contacts_list(self, file_path):    
        contacts = []
        events =('start','end','start-ns','end-ns')
        for event, elem in ET.iterparse(self.file_path, events=events):
            if event == 'end' and elem.tag == 'contact':
                contact = elem
                contacts.append(contact)
        elem.clear()
        return contacts
        #print("Superclass:",contacts)
        
class Contact(Phonebook):
    def ___init__(file_path):       # Here is a Failure !!!
        super().__init__(Contact)
               
    def search_node(self, contact, searched_tag):
        contact_template =['category','person', 'telephony', 'services', 'setup', 'features', 'mod_time', 'uniqueid' ]
        node_tag_list = []
        list_difference = []
        search_list = []
        for node in contact:
            if node.tag not in node_tag_list:
                node_tag_list.append(node.tag)
        for element in contact_template:
            if element not in node_tag_list:
                list_difference.append(element)
        
        for node in contact:
            if node.tag == searched_tag and node.tag not in list_difference:
                search_list.append(node.text)
                #print(node.text)
            else:
                if len(list_difference) != 0 and searched_tag in list_difference:
                    message = self.missed_tag(list_difference)
                    #print(message)
                    if message not in search_list:
                        search_list.append(message)                
        return  search_list
                        
    def missed_tag(self, list_difference):
        for m in list_difference:
            message = f'{m} - not assigned'
            return message
                    
         
def main():
    con = Contact('dummy.xml')
    contacts = con.contacts_list('dummy.xml')
    
    mod_time_list =[]
    for contact in contacts:
        mod_time = con.search_node(contact, 'mod_time')
        mod_time_list.append(mod_time)
    print(len(mod_time_list))
    print(mod_time_list)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    """ Input XML file definition """
    starttime=timeit.default_timer()
    main()
    print('Finished')
    # Getting % usage of virtual_memory ( 3rd field)
    print('RAM memory % used:', psutil.virtual_memory()[2])
    # Getting usage of virtual_memory in GB ( 4th field)
    print('RAM Used (GB):', psutil.virtual_memory()[3]/1000000000)
    print("Runtime:", timeit.default_timer()-starttime)
```

Could someone explain me, whats going wrong, please.

Comment: `Contact.__init__` is missing its mandatory first parameter `self`. The body is incorrect, but assuming the correct definition should have been `def __init__(self, file_path): super().__init__(file_path)`, that definition is equivalent to not defining it at all, which is what the typo is equivalent to.

Comment: @chepner this works, Thank you! You say, that the 3 _ is like delete the line completely? But how will send the file_path to the Phonbook class?

Comment: If you don't define `Contact.__init__` explicitly, it just inherits `Phonebook.__init__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with the typo because you never need to call `___init__`, and since `Contact.__init__` isn't defined, `Phonebook.__init__` seems to be sufficient for what you were trying to do with `Contact.__init__`, assuming the definition you were looking for is

```
def __init__(self, file_path):
    super().__init__(file_path)
```